# Disabling appending of WMS parameters in geting legendurl image?

Tags: qgis, getlegendgraphic

I used QGIS WMS to connect to our image server but it is displaying an error:

> Returned legend is flawed

[image]

Our image sever is using our own image render protocol in legendurl to display image:

[image]

However, QGIS is appending/overloading WMS parameters to the legendurl for the GetGraphicLegend. Is there a way to disable the WMS parameters overloading in QGIS.